Time Complexity of KnuthBendixCompletion Algorithm
I am currently studying the Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm and trying to understand the factors that contribute to its time complexity. This algorithm is used to transform a set of rewrite rules into a confluent rewrite system, ensuring that all derivable reductions of a term can be consistently reduced to a unique normal form if it exists. I know that the Knuth-Bendix completion Algorithm is a semi-decision algorithm, and that it may not always succeed.
I'd be very grateful if someone could demonstrate the time complexity of this algorithm in any specific case! Here's an example from Wikipedia using the shortlex order
$$
\left\langle x, y \mid x^3=y^3=(x y)^3=1\right\rangle
$$
Thank you!

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/167849/755. Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

@D.W. deleted from the CS stack exchange

If you have the algorithm, the Big O complexity can be calculated. What challenges are you facing?
There is a P-Complete O(n2) note here
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089054010300021X
Is this what you are looking for?

Unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for as it relates to orientability/decision problems rather than the overall time complexity
